# Laravel - Implementing Stripe payment gateaway - Error

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-8

I trying to implement stripe as payment gateaway to my laravel app, but I'm stucked on one thing..
I want to use my styles of form, it's not problem I see, but problem is with functionality..

You can see the error on the screenshot

Controller code:

```
public function handleGet()
    {
        return view('invest');
    }
  
    /**
     * handling payment with POST
     */
    public function handlePost(Request $request)
    {
        Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));
        Stripe\Charge::create ([
                "amount" => 1000 * 100,
                "currency" => "zar",
                "source" => $request->stripeToken,
                "description" => "Making test payment." 
        ]);
  
        Session::flash('success', 'Payment has been successfully processed.');
          
        return back();
    }
```

[Error after form submitting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BB8RH.jpg)

So, let me to show you my code (a View with checkout form)..:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>CryptoNomad.io | The Investment Process</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}">

        <!-- Styles -->


        <style>
            body {
                font-family: 'Nunito';
            }
        </style>
</head>
<body class="antialiased">
  <div class="max-w-6xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                <div class="flex justify-center pt-8 sm:justify-start sm:pt-0">
                    <a href="/"><img src="\images\logo\Crypto-Nomad-Logo-Black.svg" width="271.25px" height="80px"></a>
                </div>
                
                <br />
  <div class="mt-8 bg-white dark:bg-gray-800 overflow-hidden shadow sm:rounded-lg"> 
   <div class="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-1">               
  
                    @if (Session::has('success'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success text-center">
                            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a>
                            <p>{{ Session::get('success') }}</p>
                        </div>
                    @endif
                   <section class="form-container is-right has-top-margin">
                    <form role="form" action="{{ route('stripe.payment') }}" method="post" class="form validation"
                                                     data-cc-on-file="false"
                                                    data-stripe-publishable-key="{{ env('STRIPE_KEY') }}"
                                                    id="payment-form">
                        @csrf
  
                        <section class="field-container">
                                <label class='control-label'>Name on Card</label>
                        </section>
                        <section class="field-container"> 
                                <input class='form-field' size='4' type='text' placeholder="Card holder's name">
                        </section>
                          
  
                        <section class="field-container">
                                <label class='control-label'>Card Number</label>
                        </section>        
                        <section class="field-container"> 
                                <input autocomplete='off' class='form-field card-num' size='20' type='text' placeholder='Card number'>
                        </section>
  
                        <section class="field-container">
                                <label class='control-label'>CVC</label> 
                                <label class='control-label'>Expiration</label>
                        </section>
                        <section class="field-container">
                                <input autocomplete='off' class='form-field card-cvc' placeholder='e.g 415' size='4' type='text'>
                                 
                                <input class='form-field card-expiry-month' placeholder='MM' size='2' type='text'>
                                <label class='control-label investment-slash'>/ </label>
                                <input class='form-field card-expiry-year' placeholder='YY' size='2' type='text'>
                        </section>
  
                        <div class='form-row row'>
                            <div class='col-md-12 hide error form-group'>
                                <div class='alert-danger alert'>Fix the errors before you begin.</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
  
                        <section class="field-container">
                                <input class="form-submit" type="submit" value="Invest">
                        </section>
                          
                    </form>
                  </section>
                </div>
            </div>        
          <span>
                <div class="flex justify-center mt-4 sm:items-center sm:justify-between">
                    <div class="text-center text-sm text-gray-500 sm:text-left">
                        <div class="flex items-center">
                         <span class="subfooter-link">
                            <a class="subfooter-link" href="https://facebook.com/cryptonomad.io" class="ml-1 underline">
                                <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
                                Facebook
                             </span>
                            </a>
                            
                          <span class="subfooter-link">
                            <a class="subfooter-link" href="https://instagram.com/cryptonomad.io" class="ml-1 underline">
                                <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
                                Instagram
                              </span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </span>
                    <span>
                    <div class="flex justify-center mt-4 sm:items-center sm:justify-between">
                    <div class="text-center text-sm text-gray-500 sm:text-left">
                        <div class="flex items-center">
                          <span class="subfooter-link">
                            <a class="subfooter-link" href="https://www.cryptonomad.io/terms-of-service" class="ml-1 underline">
                                Terms & Conditions
                            </a>
                          </span>
                            
                            |

                          <span class="subfooter-link">
                            <a class="subfooter-link" href="https://www.cryptonomad.io/privacy-policy" class="ml-1 underline">
                                Privacy Policy
                            </a>
                           </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </span>
            </div>
        </div>
  
  
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
  
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var $form         = $(".validation");
  $('form.validation').bind('submit', function(e) {
    var $form         = $(".validation"),
        inputVal = ['input[type=email]', 'input[type=password]',
                         'input[type=text]', 'input[type=file]',
                         'textarea'].join(', '),
        $inputs       = $form.find('.required').find(inputVal),
        $errorStatus = $form.find('div.error'),
        valid         = true;
        $errorStatus.addClass('hide');
 
        $('.has-error').removeClass('has-error');
    $inputs.each(function(i, el) {
      var $input = $(el);
      if ($input.val() === '') {
        $input.parent().addClass('has-error');
        $errorStatus.removeClass('hide');
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    });
  
    if (!$form.data('cc-on-file')) {
      e.preventDefault();
      Stripe.setPublishableKey($form.data('stripe-publishable-key'));
      Stripe.createToken({
        number: $('.card-num').val(),
        cvc: $('.card-cvc').val(),
        exp_month: $('.card-expiry-month').val(),
        exp_year: $('.card-expiry-year').val()
      }, stripeHandleResponse);
    }
  
  });
  
  function stripeHandleResponse(status, response) {
        if (response.error) {
            $('.error')
                .removeClass('hide')
                .find('.alert')
                .text(response.error.message);
        } else {
            var token = response['id'];
            $form.find('input[type=text]').empty();
            $form.append("<input type='hidden' name='stripeToken' value='" + token + "'/>");
            $form.get(0).submit();
        }
    }
  
});
</script>
```

Comment: please do not put up pictures of code, code is text, it should be in your question as text in a code block

Comment: @lagbox I edited this. :) Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things that will probably help you:

1. The error states that you didn't pass in a valid publishable key. Double check that your form has something set to its `data-stripe-publishable-key` tag and that it's a valid publishable key: https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/apikeys
2. You are using Stripe.js v2, which is deprecated in favor of v3. Continuing to use v2 puts you in a harsher level of [PCI compliance](https://stripe.com/docs/security/guide#validating-pci-compliance). You should strongly consider using v3 instead: https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/integration-builder